# How do I say "I am deep in thought" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do I say "I am deep in thought" in German?

> 1. Tief in der Erinnerung versunken, dachte ich an meiner Mutter, die im Schaukelstuhl sass.

What's another alternative for this?

Comment: "deep in though" = "tief in Gedanken" or variations over that theme. The sentence you suggested uses "double thoughts" ... like "while you were deep in thought you ALSO thought of your mother." I don't think this is what you're going for so maybe you should give us the original sentence

Comment: Pierre was so deep in thought that he didnt hear the question* - In this context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [gedankenversunken](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gedankenversunken)

The german 'Duden' suggests following synonymous:

> entrückt
>
> nachdenklich, kontemplativ (pensive)
>
> selbstvergessen (abandoned)
>
> träumerisch, verträumt (dreamy, wistful)

It's just a selection, but I think those words fit best.

Answer (score 7):

The German idiom would be

> in *[etwas]* versunken

which I'd translate as

> lost in *[something]*

where *[etwas]* / *[something]* could be

- Erinnerungen / memory
- Gedanken / thought
- Tagträumen / reverie

Answer (score 5):

One possibility would be

> in Gedanken vertieft

So your sentence in the comment would be:

> Pierre war so in seine Gedanken vertieft, dass er die Frage nicht hörte.

Comment: Can't i use ' Pierre war so in seiner Erinnerung versunken, dass er die Frage nicht hörte' ??

Comment: That's possible, too.